# 502 error when calling an external web service from azure web service

Tags: web-services, wcf, azure, external

I have a web service hosted on Azure from which I need to make a request to an external web service.  When I try it on localhost it gets an expected response but from Azure I get *502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. -- There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.*
Is this a configuration problem on Azure to allow receipt of incoming responses or is it a problem with the way I am sending requests and receiving responses?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this problem is here: [Azure application gateway throws 502 when application sends 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489617/azure-application-gateway-throws-502-when-application-sends-401)  Looks like any error returned >399 causes Azure to shut down the response and send the 502.